# Formatting C++ output problem

Tags: c++

Let me examplify my problem , I've a function like:

```
void printer(int width, int hight){
    for(int i=0;i<width;++i) std::cout<<" & ";
    for(int i=0;i<hight;++i) std::cout<<" ^ ";
    std::cout<<std::endl;
}
```

my problem is function printer should always output of both for loop in same width

e.g: 
output could look (width 5):

```
   &^
 &&&^
```

or there is anyway that i print any of (from above code) `for` loop's output in constant width independent of no of times `for` loop executes

Comment: I find this question very hard to understand. Why the smiley, is this a sort of joke?

Comment: @Kerrek No, it's not any joke.

Comment: Your function has **two** inputs `width` and `height`. Give us a couple of examples with different values and the expected output. Maybe then we will understand what you are asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Question is unclear.  Are you looking for something like the following ?

```
void printer(int amps, int carets, int overallWidth){
    for (int i = amps + carets; i < overallWidth; i++)  std::cout<<" ";  // leading padding
    for (int i=0;i<amps;++i) std::cout<<"&";
    for (int i=0;i<carets;++i) std::cout<<"^";
    std::cout<<std::endl;
}
```

The change was just to add a loop for outputting the padding.  (also changed the parameters name for clarity)

```
printer(1,1,5);
printer(3,1,5);
```

would then produce the output shown in example

```
   &^
 &&&^
```

and of course, rather than being passed as a parameter, the overallWidth variable could be hardcoded; an implicit constant of the printer() function.

**Edit**:
The snippet above stayed very close to that of the question. There are however **more idiomatic approaches**, for example the following "one liner", which uses one of the string constructor overloads to produce the strings of repeated characters, and iomanip's setw() to produce the padding.

```
void printer(int amps, int carets, int overallWidth){
   std::cout << setiosflags(ios::right) << setw(overalWidth) 
             << string(amps, '&') + string (carets, '^')
             << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: is there any solution from `boost` lib (easy one)?

Comment: This solution is overly complex given using io streams.

Comment: @Chad, Mr Anubis; yes there are much easier, or for the least more idiomatic solutions.  See for eg my edit.

Comment: wow , that last solution is awesome small and good , thanks a lot)

Comment: That's a good one (and shows as my answer that `setw` is workable).

Comment: Can you please also tell any technique so that i can do same as my question but with string e.g "0.o" not for single char , since std::string(5,"0.o") won't work.

Answer (score 1):

Look into `<iomanip>`.  Using `cout` you can specify a width.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   cout << setiosflags(ios::left) << setw(10) << "Hello"
        << setiosflags(ios::right) << setw(20) << "World!";

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: your solution won't work when you need to set width of two outputs from `for` loops

Comment: setw() does not require a constant nor does it require to be known at compile time.  Not sure why this wouldn't work in any scenario?